# Is 'bounded memory growth' considered a memory leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I am programming a game using XCode's sprite kit where the different objects appear and disappear. While monitoring the memory, I noticed every time a different object appears, the memory would increase slightly (then the object will disappear keeping the memory higher than before), but after all objects have appeared once, the memory doesn't seem to increase. I plan on uploading this game to the appstore, so I was wondering if this would be considered a memory leak (and if I should worry/ dedicate a lot of time to trying to figure out how to 'fix' this)?

Comment: What does the leaks instrument say ? If you see red bars you got leaks regardless. How do you monitor the memory ? looking at the Xcode memory bar is not enough

Comment: In short: no. Consider caching mechanisms employed by Sprite Kit and other frameworks.